# Microsoft Media Player Platform with AVC encoded MP4 on Win8

Tags: windows-8, media-player

I have an AVC encoded MP4 file that I would like to play in the app. But it always failed to play and the error message is "MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED : HRESULT - 0xC00D36B4". How should I resolve the problem?

BTW, the url is here:

http://coursecast2.nus.edu.sg/Panopto/Content/Sessions/1290e053-9cd0-4cda-812a-01a8bcd9a13d/91d06ea8-aaf8-463b-b8f3-1771109ff56e-e746270b-0142-413e-8587-48080a4c1c16.mp4

Thanks

EDIT 1:

I am using C# with XAML.

XAML:

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <mmppf:MediaPlayer x:Name="test" MediaFailed="failed"/>
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        this.test.Source = new Uri("http://coursecast2.nus.edu.sg/Panopto/Content/Sessions/1290e053-9cd0-4cda-812a-01a8bcd9a13d/91d06ea8-aaf8-463b-b8f3-1771109ff56e-e746270b-0142-413e-8587-48080a4c1c16.mp4");

    }

    private void failed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        String fail = e.ToString();
    }
```

Edit 2:
[image: This is the encoding format of the MP4 file]

Comment: What are you using? C# JS HTML? Post some Code...

Comment: @Smartis i am using C# and Microsoft Player Framework. I am testing it using very simple codes but I will post them anyways.

Comment: Currently i dont think it's code, more the File...

Comment: @Smartis I am thinking of that too. I will post a screenshot of the encoding format of that mp4 file.